# Not getting data form java function in another function

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, facebook-graph-api

If you view this question thank you in advance!, I am working on pulling data from Facebook.

I am trying to pull the username from Facebook so i can use it in a later stage I have embedded the following code in the FB Root div.

I know the retrieve works! however i am not able to pass it on to the function "returndata" I am relative new to javascript could you please help me out? i have tried everything

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) 
    {
GetID = response.username
return GetID})


function returndata(){
get = response
return get


};
```

Comment: what is the returndata() function supposed to do?

Comment: Later i use this to pass on the username into AS3 and other Javascript functions, i just need to send the username details to the function "returndata" thanks for your fast reply. 

P.S the rest of the script that is not visible works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returndata method should take an argument, and you should call it from the facebook callback:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) {
    returndata(response.username);
});

function returndata(username) {
    // do whatever you need here, with access to username
};
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working, it is not returning data

Comment: I asked above what you want "returndata" to do, and you said "i just need to send the username details to the function returndata", which is exactly what happens here. So, what would actually like the function to do?